# How to add rule to firebase to give a group of user ids access to a path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have a document in Firebase structured like so:

```
{
  applications: {
    id_1: {
      feature: {
        a: true,
        b: false
      },
      users: ['user_id_1', 'user_id_2']
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add a rule that ensures only users in the `users` array can read and write to the application with id === `id_1`.

I have tried adding the following rules but still seem to be able to read and write data when logged in as `user_id_3`

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1643846400000",  // 2022-2-3
    ".write": "now < 1643846400000",  // 2022-2-3,
    "applications": {
      "$appId": {
        ".write": "data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".read": "data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add a rule to give access to a group of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasChild` function used in your rules example only *checks for keys* that are children of the path you specified. In your case, the path is `applications/$appId/users`.

The data stored at `applications/$appId/users` is an array, so the key for each item in the array would be the item's index. This is why your rule doesn't work - you are checking for `user_id_1` or `user_id_2`, but the keys in your data are `0` and `1`. There is no current equivalent for "array contains" when writing Firebase rules.

**One solution** would be to change the data structure of `applications/$appId/users` to be an object instead of an array. For example:

```
{
  applications: {
    id_1: {
      feature: {
        a: true,
        b: false
      },
      users: {
        user_id_1: true,
        user_id_2: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then using `hasChild` in your rules will work since the user's id is a child of `applications/$appId/users`.

*On thing to note about your security in general:* By granting write access to all of `$appId`, you are giving any user at `applications/$appId/users` the ability to edit any other user's permission. Since they are free to read/write all data at that location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That has technically solved the issue I had but it has also raised another question. Since  it's a bit different I have posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711696/how-to-add-rule-in-firebase-to-prevent-read-of-parent-element